# Indoor Birds of Paradise leaf turning yellow with dark brown spots

Tags: houseplants

The newest leaf on our 2m tall birds of paradise (Strelitzia Nicolai variety) has started developing yellow marks with small brown spots. It's a real pity as those leaves take almost a year to come out and open fully.
I'm unsure as to what's causing this... here are a few additional data points about our birds of paradise:

- It gets a lot of sun all year being right behind a south facing window (we are in London, UK)
- This latest leaf though gets not much direct sunlight being pretty high and right below the sloping ceiling
- The penultimate leaf that we got bent 9 months ago. The stem lacked strength and bent in multiple places. We fixed it with some poles and thin rope and the leaf has so far survived.
- We have had some scale insects on it for over a year which have been a pain to get rid off. They can still be controlled through regular cleaning although they leave a very sticky clear deposit on the leaves
- The birds of paradise is watered every week and once a month or so we mix in the water some fully balanced liquid feed (Chempak N3)
- We have had the plant for a 2 years or so and it has not been repotted so far
- A new leaf has started growing but the yellowing and spotting of that latest leaf seems to continue to develop.

Thanks in advance for any help/pointers you can provide!
Cheers

Here are some pictures:

2 weeks ago...

[image: 2 weeks ago]
[image: 2 weeks ago]

Today...

[image: Today]